# VSTS msbuild: How to use parameters instead of profile? Error: Could not find __.dll

Tags: msbuild, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have a simple "Hello World" mvc web application that I am attempting to build in VSTS.  My steps are:

1. Get Sources
2. Run msbuild on a single project
3. Publish artifact (publish directory)

Everything works fine whenever I use a profile for msbuild, but I would like to just pass the parameter commands in instead.  When I do this I get the following error:

> Error : Copying file bin\WebApp01.dll to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\WebApp01.dll failed. Could not find file 'bin\WebApp01.dll'.

What mistake am I making with my msbuild parameters?  How do I properly duplicate a simple file system profile?

Parameters (error'ing):

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:Configuration="Release" /p:Platform="Any CPU" /t:WebPublish /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem /p:publishUrl=PublishToOctopus
```

Profile (works):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <publishUrl>PublishToOctopus</publishUrl>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>False</DeleteExistingFiles>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `/p:DeployOnBuild=true`, you can use the normal `Build` target. You directly called `WebPublish` (`/t:WebPublish`) which expects a build to already have happened but since it doesn't, the  file is missing from the expected location.